# ApolloClient createHttpLink typescript error 2739

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I am creating my React frontend, using apollo client to connect to my apollo server:

`App.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import "./app.scss";

import {
  ApolloLink,
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

function App() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    **link**: createHttpLink({
      uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      credentials: "include",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello there</h1>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am using typescript by the way.

For some reason I am getting a typescript error. When I hover over the word `link` parameter in the ApolloClient config, it shows this:

```
Type 'ApolloLink' is missing the following properties from type 'ApolloLink': onError, setOnError ts(2739)

ApolloClient.d.ts(20, 5): 

The expected type comes from property 'link' which is declared here on type 'ApolloClientOptions<NormalizedCacheObject>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HttpLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#the-httplink-object) of `@apollo/client` package. `apollo-link-http` package is included in `@apollo/client` package, see [Migrate to Apollo client v3](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#apollo-link-and-apollo-link-http)

> All `apollo-link`, `apollo-link-http`, and `apollo-link-http-common` functionality is included in the `@apollo/client` package.

> As part of migrating, we recommend removing all `apollo-link`, `apollo-link-http`, and `apollo-link-http-common` dependencies.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';

function App() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
      credentials: 'include',
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello there</h1>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package version: `"@apollo/client": "^3.4.7"`